# Ionic 3 animation not working

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am using `Ionic 3.6.0` and trying to animate items list when removed… I have embedded `state` in the response of the list… I also found that `* => void` does not work (not sure)… so I rearranged the code as following:

.ts:

```
animations: [
 trigger('listItemState', [
    state('in', style({opacity: 1, height:'*', minHeight: '*'})),
    state('out', style({opacity: 0, height: '1px', minHeight: '1px;'})),
    transition('in => out', animate('0.25s 10 ease-out'))
 ])
]
```

and this is part of the html `[@listItemState]="job.state" *ngFor="let job of jobsList; let i = index;"`

the `job.state` is embedded as I said and holds value `in`

In the function remove at .ts:

```
 remove(i) {
  job.state = job.state === 'in' ? 'out' : 'in';
  this.jobsList.splice(i , 1);
 }
```

I have done similar with an accordion list and its working… but I can’t figure out why this one does not work! https://stackoverflow.com/a/45659417/7266219